# I am making a mineflayer pvp bot but it only attacks once

Tags: javascript, minecraft, mineflayer

I am trying to make a pvp minecraft bot using mineflayer in javascript. This is my function for if the bot is requested to pvp:

```
bot.loadPlugin(pvp)
bot.on('chat', (username, message) =>{
if (message === 'fight me') {
    const player = bot.players[username]

    if (!player) {
      bot.chat("I can't see you.")
      return
    }
    bot.chat("Get ready to PvP in 10 seconds!")
    const sword = bot.inventory.items().find(item => item.name.includes('sword'))
    if (sword) bot.equip(sword, 'hand')
    const shield = bot.inventory.items().find(item => item.name.includes('shield'))
    if (shield) bot.equip(shield, 'off-hand')
   
    sleep(1500).then(() => {
    
    beeingAlive()
    bot.chat(`/tp notbreadbutter ${username}`)
    bot.pvp.attack(player.entity)})
    
  }

  if (message === 'stop') {
    bot.pvp.stop()
    
  }})
```

I want the bot to know when the player gets killed. I also want the bot to know if the bot itself gets killed. How should i modify my code?

Comment: That's seems normal. You make it with `sleep(1500)` which is not a timer that will run each 1500 ticks or something. You should use a scheduler for this

Comment: Ok thanks... I tried it, it seems to work.. but how can i make the bot know if the player it was attacking has been killed or if the bot itself has been killed?

Comment: @Bread_butter That sounds like a different question. Please create a new question and ask that there.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you to self-answer for this issue and ask a new question if you have another problem